# Getting the newest rows that match a constraint

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an SQL query that will:

- Find the newest values
- Where `Name` is `IN ("Dryer", "Temperature")`
- Not use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` (Name isn't indexed, so these are really intensive; not my choice unfortunately)

My table consists of `Id`, `Name`, `Time`, `Value`.

For example, my table consists of rows like this:

```
Id   | Name           | Value | Time
-----+----------------+-------+--------------------
1    | Temperature    | 50    | 2015-05-12 14:30:00
2    | Something      | 14    | 2015-05-12 14:30:00
3    | Dryer          | 1     | 2015-05-12 14:30:00
4    | Temperature    | 51    | 2015-05-12 14:31:00
5    | Dryer          | 0     | 2015-05-12 14:31:00
6    | Something      | 14    | 2015-05-12 14:32:00
7    | Temperature    | 52    | 2015-05-12 14:32:00
8    | Dryer          | 1     | 2015-05-12 14:32:00
```

And in this case, I would like to SELECT rows 7 and 8.

This query works, but the performance is far from ideal:

```
SELECT 
    name, value, timestmp
FROM
    datalog
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Is there a way of doing this query that won't perform terribly on a non-`Name`-indexed table?

Comment: don't `select * ` when grouping by `name` !

Comment: Because it won't work as expected

Comment: Why don't you index `name`? Actually it should probably be normalized into a lookup table.

Comment: @dan08 It's not my choice sadly and I don't have permission to change it.

Comment: If you can't create index and have to do it quickly, you can try your luck by fetch the latest 1000 ( or less records) and pick the matches. It usually works since you are interested in the "latest" match and the 1000 records can be retrieved quickly if your table is ordered by time. 
If you can't find your matches in the result, you can increase the limit until your query is totally useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without group by and indices you're a bit out of luck. The only option I see is to create a subquery for each name and union that together, but that only works when the names are known in advance and is only feasible when the query is created dynamically.

The query would look like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM datalog WHERE name='dryer' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM datalog WHERE name='temperature' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
--etc.
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it, so you'll have to try it out to see if it's actually faster. In theory it should perform better though.

But as others have said, the proper solution is to get the indices fixed. But from your comments it seems that in your case that's more of an human issue than a programming one.

Comment: Doing this actually works really well performance-wise. It just sucks that there doesn't seem to be a better way of doing it without indices.